# Difference between a "block" and a "building" in this situation

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, british-english

Here is a brief description about my residence:

> There are around fifty apartment buildings in ABC Garden. 
>   Each building has thirty stories, and there are 10 flats in each story.
>   One day, a stranger spoke to me telling that he was my new neighbour.
>   He told me something like this,"...we live in the same **block.**"

I am wondering if he was trying to tell me that we live in the same building but on different floors? Or A block is equivalent to a building in English language?

Comment: I think it's [block](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/block_1#block_1__2) 2a. "an area of buildings in a town or city with streets on all four sides". I'm not very sure because he used the word *flat*, suggesting that it was in another dialect I'm not quite familiar with.

Comment: Dear kitty, read this article on block on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_block). Or it can mean [11(n)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/block):

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A block isn't typically equivalent to a building in American English. It means something a bit different.

In American English, a block signifies a square (or possibly rectangular) area surrounded on all sides by roads. You'll typically find these in downtown areas of cities, not in the suburban areas.

Here's a concrete example to make this clearer. Here is a random subsection of Brooklyn (in New York City) [taken from Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/New+York,+NY/@40.70465,-74.0927749,10.58z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b:0xc80b8f06e177fe62):

[image]

Each of those rectangular sections is called a block.

Typically, one would say that they live **on** the same block. He was trying to tell you that he lives a couple of buildings away, but on the same block.

Comment: Why do you think that is the meaning intended rather than an apartment block? If the quote specifically says "in", then isn't that evidence that they're not talking about street blocks?

Comment: But note the usage **in** the same block, as well as the reference to a **flat**. So my guess is the speaker is British (or the passage is translated from a Continental language), and was referring to two apartments in the same building of a project.

Comment: Also, while a "block" can refer to the rectangle on a map (as in, "around the block"), it can also mean both sides of a section of street that forms one side of such a block (say, E 46th between Foster and D), and that's who I would expect to attend a "block party".

Comment: Well, by looking at the map, one can see that a block as describe by Alex K is exactly the block as described by david.

Comment: According Merriam Webste, entry #3, a block also means a large building divided into separate units such as apartments, shops. However, this sense is more common in BE than in AE.

Comment: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/block

Answer (score 4):

We live in the same block.

The noun block is used in varied senses. Among them, it also means a large building divided into separate units, such as flats/apartments, offices, or shops. Here, it has been used in this sense.

The same block means the same building; It may mean that we live on the same floor or different floors of the same building. But as we are referring to our neighbor,  it is most probably that the sentence means that we live on the same floor of the building.

Comment: As you mention in your [other comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73373/difference-between-a-block-and-a-building-in-this-situation/73375#comment140718_73375), this isn't so common in American English. If I learned that someone lived in my building, I wouldn't say "We live in the same _block_," even if a dictionary would back me up. Instead, I'd say, "We live in the same _building_,"  or maybe, "in the same _complex_."

Comment: J.R. I always agree with you; I ain't a native speaker.  BTW, I have said in my comments that it's more common in BE than in AE. Thanks for your valued comments.

Answer (score 1):

Block here refers to the area or surrounding where your building is located. Alex has provided a detailed answer too. 
I would like to add another perspective. 
Let us not take the literal meaning of a block, on a contextual note he would have referred to "living close by" or "living in the same neighborhood".